# Can anyone help me with this picture/ painting and the translation? Any help would be appreciated

Tags: translation

please help: picture/ painting and the translation? Any help would be appreciated

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

枝頭鳴春

It should be a painting of some birds sitting on the branches singing for the spring.

The smaller characters 鳴九 could be the name of the painter.

Comment: I can make out the first three characters so I search for 枝頭鳴? and found 枝頭鳴春 on the first page